# Setting NULL Values for ForeignKeys - Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following problem: I would like to create two tables in my database: 1. Team and 2. Match. The table representing a match has two foreign keys referencing the team table. I would like to have the deletion of a team from the team table set the corresponding records in the match table to NULL. Is such a solution possible with Entity Framework?

```
    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Faculty { get; set; }
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
        public List<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; } = new List<Match>();
        public List<Match> VisitorMatches { get; set; } = new List<Match>();

    }

    public class Match
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int? HomeTeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

        public int? VisitorTeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team VisitorTeam { get; set; }

        public virtual Statistics Statistics { get; set; }  
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                .HasOne(m => m.VisitorTeam)
                .WithMany(t => t.VisitorMatches)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.VisitorTeamId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                .HasOne(m => m.HomeTeam)
                .WithMany(t => t.HomeMatches)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeTeamId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

My previous solution generates an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Match_Team_VisitorTeamId' on table 'Match' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

[image]

I tried modifying the cascading behavior, but without success - I'm still encountering errors. I have reviewed many forum posts, but none specifically address setting NULL values in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that even with SQL query -- will also fail when you create the second foreign key. It's violating 1NF. Ideally, you need to create the third table that holds Team ID and Match ID, i.e.

```
public class MatchTeamCombination
{
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public bool IsHomeTeam { get; set; } // optional to determine home / visitor team
}
```

Then adjust the FKs as needed and you can just change the combination there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:`.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` for both relationships, like:

```
           modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
               .HasOne(m => m.VisitorTeam)
               .WithMany(t => t.VisitorMatches)
               .HasForeignKey(m => m.VisitorTeamId)
               .IsRequired(false)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
                .HasOne(m => m.HomeTeam)
                .WithMany(t => t.HomeMatches)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeTeamId)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: It doesn't cause an error, but when I try to delete a team that is in the match table, an error pops up until I delete the match in which that team is located.

Comment: @Johnny Bravo ,  Yes, when you delete the team that used in match will accour error. If you want to remove the relationship betwen the team and match by removed the team, you can create another table to  holds Team ID and Match ID .

Comment: Okay, but is there any way to set an option in Entity Framework that would work in such a way that deleting a team from the Team table would set NULL values for that deleted value in the Match table? For example, using ClientSetNull?